# All URL are pointing to root instead we need a project folder

Tags: node.js, polymer, gulp

I am new to node and gulp
I create a project and its working fine but I am facing an issue when i am hosting my project on some web server (tomcat). All URL are pointing to root instead  we need a  project folder

Please guide me what i am missing

```
currently : http://localhost:8000/
I need something like this : http://localhost:8000/projectName/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this on applications where I have one application that essentially builds another application. They are tightly coupled in my case so I created a single repository in git for both projects.

For your case, if its only a single app & only a routing issue, I would configure apache or HAProxy to redirect `http://localhost:8000/` to `http://localhost:8000/projectName`. I have only done this in nginx & HAProxy but it should be easy enough with other setups. [This tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html) might help.

Comment: Thank you for response
i do not have a single app in that folder . I redirected the url but all JS and CSS are looking for root dir

Comment: I use a static server with nginx aliasing & redirecting because with multiple apps you many have the same files (plus its faster). You could alternatively host them cheaply on AWS as well. 

```
```

Comment: T create your own static server, you can use rack, superstatic, or whatever for static server but nginx controls the routing for me.
  
Here is a image example. My static app has this mapping set up for img, css, js, fonts, assets for each sub application.

    location /my_root/my_app/img {
        root /root/app/path/app_name/public/img;
    }