# Gulp serve Polymer starter kit issue

Tags: gulp, polymer-1.0

It's the 1st time I'm using gulp and can't get it to run properly as chrome loads and can't find any of the imports:

```html
http://localhost:3000/demos/polymer/site/styles/main.css 
(index):50 GET http://localhost:3000/demos/polymer/site/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js 
(index):200 GET http://localhost:3000/demos/polymer/site/scripts/app.js 
(index):54 GET http://localhost:3000/demos/polymer/site/elements/elements.html
```

I've read a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004490/all-url-are-pointing-to-root-instead-we-need-a-project-folder/29007124#29007124) but I think this could be a port issue? or me just not "gulping"? correctly.

I have bitnami apache on my machine.

I tried adding a virtual host redirect and no success.

localhost http://localhost:3000
    PolymerStart http://localhost/demos/polymer/site/app/

Answer (score 0):

Ended up re-installing polymer kit on root. I found similar issues [here](https://github.com/thomasstreet/famous-angular-starter/issues/6)

copying bower_components didn't do the trick in my case.